# Give each element a class incremented by 1

Tags: jquery

I have this html:

```
<div class="nbhds-overlay active" style="display: block;">

    <h3><href="#">one</a></h3>
    <h3><href="#">two</a></h3>
    <h3><href="#">three</a></h3>
    <h3><href="#">four</a></h3>

</div>
```

I want to give each `h3` a class of `myclassSOMENUMBER` where `SOMENUMBER` is incremented by 1. I know how many elements there are, but it would be good if it could be done without knowing the number of elements as well ( i think that would be a recursive function? ).

Anyway, I tried the following, which gives each `h3` a class of `myclass1 myclass3` (understandably) , but I do not know how to target each one separately.

Basically in this concrete example they should have the following classes when done correctly: `myclass1` `myclass2` `myclass3` and `myclass4` respectively.

```
function classesForNbhds() {
        var count = $('.nbhds-overlay h3').length;
        for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
            $('.nbhds-overlay h3').addClass('myclass'+i);
            i++;
        };
    }

    classesForNbhds();
```

Comment: Yu're supposed to accept the best answer not the fastest. I initally accepted yours and then came back and so another which seemed better and I upvoted your q. You downvoted my q because I didn't accept your answer??? :D

Comment: You're saying it wasn't u? Anyway I don't even care TBO, bottom line is I really do appreciate the time you took to answer my Q and I upvoted it and am glad I did, I just accepted the answer that seemed simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.nbhds-overlay h3').addClass(function(i) {
    return 'myClass' + (i + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nbhds-overlay active" style="display: block;">

    <h3><href="#">one</a></h3>
    <h3><href="#">two</a></h3>
    <h3><href="#">three</a></h3>
    <h3><href="#">four</a></h3>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `$().each()` method to iterate over the elements. Then assign the class using `addClass()`

```
$(".nbhds-overlay h3").each(function(i) {
  $(this).addClass("Myclass" + (i+1));
});
```

the first parameter in each method callback will be the index of the element. Here it is `i`

Comment: The first would be 0 in this case you need (i + 1)

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Thanks for the suggestion. Just edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

use $('.nbhds-overlay h3').each() for iterating over all h3 tags:

```
   function classesForNbhds() {
        $('.nbhds-overlay h3').each(function(i,s) {
          $(this).addClass('myclass'+(i+1));
        });
    }
```